# How to read cocos2d-x CCLog traces on a remote iphone?

Tags: iphone, debugging, console, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to debug a cocos2d-x app on an iPhone:

I can read my (CCLog/printf) traces in the Xcode console logs when I run the app in the simulator.
Why don't they show up when i connect the device by USB and check for them in Xcode's **Organizer** console output ?

Notes:

I can read  my app's objective-C NSLog traces in Xcode's Organizer console output.

I can read my CCLog strings; when using the unix command `strings` on the iPhone's binary.

update for LearnCocos2D:
Yes, i'm using the app built in Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/

Comment: are you testing release configuration? Because most likely CCLog is disabled in release by default, whereas NSLog is enabled in release unless you set a secific compiler flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this trick:
you modify the CCLog function in CCCommon.mm, by putting NSLog instead of printf:

```
void CCLog(const char * pszFormat, ...)
{
    printf("Cocos2d: ");
    char szBuf[kMaxLogLen];

    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, pszFormat);
    vsnprintf(szBuf, kMaxLogLen, pszFormat, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    printf("%s", szBuf);
   // printf("\n");
    NSLog(@"%s", szBuf);
}
```

and you add:

```
#import <Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h>
```

at the top of the file.

Comment: Not working for cocos2d-js 3.0 :-( CCLog is depricated.